# eslint + typescript + path in tsconfig: ESLint: Unable to resolve path to module '@components/some-module'.(import/no-unresolved)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I add typescript config for paths (alias):

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "public"
  ]
}
```

After that I try import somthing like this:

```
import Header from '@components/header';
```

And now I get error in eslint: `ESLint: Unable to resolve path to module '@components/header'.(import/no-unresolved)`

Answer (score 44):

I found a solution in this: [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript)

`npm i -D eslint-plugin-import @typescript-eslint/parser eslint-import-resolver-typescript`

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  'settings': {
    'import/resolver': {
      'typescript': {},
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: I had to add "compilerOptions": { "moduleResolution": "node" } additionally to tsconfig.json in order to ESlint stop complaining when import from node_modules.

Comment: Correct answer. Finally after losing 2 hours for this and giving up to just disable warning, I found this simple solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this:[eslint-import-resolver-alias](https://github.com/johvin/eslint-import-resolver-alias)

`npm install -D eslint-import-resolver-alias`

.eslintrc

```json
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "alias": {
        "map": [
          [
            "@",
            "./src"
          ]
        ],
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".ts",
          ".tsx",
          ".jsx",
          ".json"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```